# R package to go from CSV to CSVW JSON-LD

Tags: r, json-ld

I have a dataframe (or a csv file I suppose) like this:

```
"Financial Institution","Rate","Insured By"
Saven Financial,1.55,FSRA
Neo Financial,1.55,CDIC
```

I wish to convert this to a CSVW JSON-LD format as per this article on [tabular data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/dataset#approach).

I've hand coded a version in Rmarkdown. See below.
Is there an R package that makes this transformation easy?

```
---
  title: "Structured Demo 3 - Test"
---

<script type="application/ld+json">  
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Dataset",
  "name":"Canadian High-Interest Savings Accounts",
  "description": "Up-to-date and unbiased table of rates of high-interest savings accounts from Canadian banks and credit unions along with their insurer.",
  "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Company X"
  },
  "mainEntity" : {
    "@type" : "csvw:Table",
    "csvw:tableSchema": {
      "csvw:columns": [
        {
          "csvw:name": "Financial Institution",
          "csvw:datatype": "string",
          "csvw:cells": [
            {
              "csvw:value": "Saven Financial",
              "csvw:primaryKey": "Saven Financial"
            },
            {
              "csvw:value": "Neo Financial",
              "csvw:primaryKey": "Neo Financial"
            }]
        },
        {
          "csvw:name": "Rate",
          "csvw:datatype": "string",
          "csvw:cells": [
            {
              "csvw:value": "1.55",
              "csvw:primaryKey": "Saven Financial"
            },
            {
              "csvw:value": "1.55",
              "csvw:primaryKey": "Neo Financial"
            }]
        },
        {
          "csvw:name": "Insured By",
          "csvw:datatype": "string",
          "csvw:cells": [
            {
              "csvw:value": "FSRA",
              "csvw:primaryKey": "Saven Financial"
            },
            {
              "csvw:value": "CDIC",
              "csvw:primaryKey": "Neo Financial"
            }]
        }]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points, note that if you're using the Tabular Metadata standard, the context is rather prescribed. See, for example Example 2 in [Tabular Metadata](https://www.w3.org/TR/tabular-metadata/). However, Google may be accepting a semantically equivalent version using the schema.org context.

The CSVW specs do have some strict requirements on referencing the table from the table description, which perhaps Google has relaxed.

I published a [Note](https://www.w3.org/TR/csvw-html/) about embedding metadata in HTML some time ago, and that might point to more usage patterns used by Google and/or the Structured Data Testing Tool.

Regarding support for CSVW in R, there is an [implementation](https://github.com/davideceolin/rcsvw) which was started, but shows very low conformance. It certainly would be great if it were advanced. Perhaps there's something in there you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an R package - [csvwr](https://github.com/Robsteranium/csvwr) - that helps you derive a csvw table annotation based upon what R already knows about your data frame (i.e. identifying the right XML Schema Datatype to suit each column).

Per the instructions for [writing csvw](https://robsteranium.github.io/csvwr/articles/read-write-csvw.html#how-do-i-create-csvw-table-annotations):

```
library(csvwr)

# Given a data frame
d <- data.frame(x=c("a","b","c"), y=1:3)

# Derive a schema
s <- derive_table_schema(d)

# Create metadata (as a list)
m <- create_metadata(tables=s)

# Serialise the metadata to JSON
j <- jsonlite::toJSON(m)

jsonlite::prettify(j)
#> {
#>     "@context": [
#>         "http://www.w3.org/ns/csvw"
#>     ],
#>     "tables": {
#>         "columns": [
#>             {
#>                 "name": "x",
#>                 "titles": "x",
#>                 "datatype": "string"
#>             },
#>             {
#>                 "name": "y",
#>                 "titles": "y",
#>                 "datatype": "integer"
#>             }
#>         ]
#>     }
#> }
#>
```

Note that csvw has a default annotation - for any csv file - and a lot of the boilerplate you have in the question applies by default due to the jsonld context (i.e. you don't need to write all of that out explicitly). It might be worth playing with some of the csv2json tools to see if those give you what you need.